# img attribute question re: IE --> won't display native width of images, reverts to 1px wide

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question regards my personal photography website. I use the following javascript to generate random image sequences each time the page is loaded or refreshed:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () {
  var ar = [];
  function returnRandomUnique() {
    if ( !ar.length) {
      for (var i = 16; i > 0; i--)
        ar[ar.length] = i;
    }
      return '<img alt="photograph" class="picture" src="images/work_images/image_' + ar.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * ar.length) ,1) + '.jpg"  height="550" width=""/>';
   }
  // test
  var str = [];
 for (var j = 0; j <16; j++){
    str[str.length] = returnRandomUnique();
  }
 $("#mainwork").append(str.join(''));
 });
  </script>
```

My html and css both validate (css has border radius warnings for three buttons) and the site looks good on everything except any version of IE. The problem is that the width of each image varies and cannot be specified (heights are all consistent at 550px --the site scrolls left to right.)

IE displays each image as a line, 550px high by 1px wide. I'd like to find a value that will allow the images to display properly or force IE to use a different html page that will have a fixed layout (remove the random image generator javascript) where I can add the values as appropriate. I don't know how to force one browser to use a different html file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not really familiar with javascript, but found this in a library and modified it as best as I could to fit my needs.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `width=""`. If I remember correctly, that screws up IE.

---

Testing it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4pE7E/

In IE9/8/7, it does indeed cause the image to be `1px` wide.

Comment: Thanks. I'v removed that portion of the code. Everything still validates and it looks ok on FF, Safari and Chrome. I can't check IE here at home, but will check back in and let you know if it was actually that easy. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem. You can check it in IE with [http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/](http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/)

Comment: Not rendering any images at all when viewed through that link. But due to the number of images it often takes a few seconds or more to render them. Perhaps that screenshot is taken too quickly.

Comment: If you like, you could write the link in a comment here, then delete it in a couple of minutes after I've checked it. Or we can just wait till later.

Comment: Screenshot from IE9: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti0Dy.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti0Dy.png) - and it looks the same in IE8.

Comment: That looks pretty good. I'll check more when I can and confirm, but if IE 8 and 9 work that's fine with me (I'm not going to worry about anything older than 8!) Thanks so much for your help, Matt.

Comment: You're welcome. Once you've checked and if it's all good, please [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).